# Why is my transaction not being found?

Tags: web3.py

This is my first time trying anything with web3 and my transaction isn't sending I have checked the documentation and everything seems to be correct so i don't know why it isn't working.[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
from web3 import Web3


gnache_url = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(gnache_url))

print(web3.isConnected())

account1 = "0x9D7700325246447A5e481f355167637e1a2f2a0A"
account2 = "0x3F764C22F69Da4754b16796cD4D2e5383FE43a5e"

private_key = "9aa34d6f42d04aa53146cdbba11a3e7e45d10971ae5b2bc49683d64b21cfa2b1"

#building the transaction
balance1 = web3.eth.get_balance(account1)
print(balance1)
nonce = web3.eth.getTransaction(account1)
transaction_info = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': account2,
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'ether'),
    'gas': 20000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50','gwei')
}
signed_transaction = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction_info,private_key)
print(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
#print(signed_transaction)
#transaction_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
#print(transaction_hash)
```

Comment: Can you include the code as text? Do you know which line causes the error? The 'gas' parameter is low, the absolute minimum is 21000, and for contracts you'll need more.

Comment: I changed the the gas parameter to higher and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues:

To initialize nonce you have to call `web3.eth.get_transaction_count` and you were calling `web3.eth.getTransaction`.

```
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(account1)
```

For a simple ether transfer the minimum is 21000, anything less will fail.

```
'gas': 21000,
```

Note: Probably you want to change `web3.eth.account.signTransaction` to `web3.eth.account.sign_transaction` the standard python naming convention.